# What are the rules for GCP vm instance's metadata

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, metadata, gcloud

in my `gcloud compute instance create` command I'd like to set some metadata:

```
--metadata=listofstuff=thing1,thing2,thing3
```

It fails.
I can't seem to find any mention of the rules with respect escaping.

Iv'e tried:

```
--metadata='listofstuff=thing1,thing2,thing3'

--metadata="listofstuff=thing1,thing2,thing3"

--metadata=listofstuff='thing1,thing2,thing3'

--metadata=listofstuff="thing1,thing2,thing3"

--metadata='listofstuff=thing1,thing2,thing3'

--metadata=listofstuff=thing1\,thing2\,thing3
```

Surly there is a dusty tome somewhere that covers this _very important topic.

Comment: It looks like you are following this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/setting-custom-metadata#set_during_creation
By the way, are you getting any error messages with respect to the instance creation with the metadata that you were trying to add?

Comment: It doesn't say explicitly. But I've tried the command with all my other options with the meta data line and without , and with other metadata lines, and it's only the key=X,Y,Z metadata included.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options:

`value`:

```
thing1,thing2,thing3
```

Note: Be careful to avoid `\n` etc.

```bash
gcloud compute instances add-metadata ${INSTANCE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--metadata-from-file=foo=value
```

See [`gcloud topic flags-file`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/flags-file)

`flags.yaml`:

```
--metadata:
    bar: "thing1,thing2,thing3"
```

```bash
gcloud compute instances add-metadata ${INSTANCE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--flags-file=flags.yaml
```

And:

```bash
gcloud compute instances describe ${INSTANCE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="json(metadata.items.filter(\"key\":\"foo OR bar\"))"

{
  "metadata": {
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "bar",
        "value": "thing1,thing2,thing3"
      },
      {
        "key": "foo",
        "value": "thing1,thing2,thing3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest approach would be [`gcloud topic escaping`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping)

```
gcloud compute instances create example-instance1 \
--metadata ^:^key1="value1":key2=value2:key3=value3Index1,value3Index2,valueIndex3:key4=value4
```