# Escaping characters in a list sent as environment variable to GCP Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I am trying to create a Github workflow about deploying a GCP Cloud Run service with a list of strings as environment variable and need help defining the environment variable properly with regards to the the escaping of characters.

Here's my gcloud command:

```
gcloud run deploy my-service --image \
       europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/projectName/containers/my-service:$(echo ${GITHUB_SHA} | cut -c1-8) \
       --project PROJECT --platform managed --region europe-west3 \
       --memory 4Gi \
       --timeout 900 \
       --set-env-vars="my_list=["one", "two", "three"]"
```

I would appreciate some help defining the syntax of the environment variable `my_list`.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73706014/609290)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of an environment variable file as described [here.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var)
Doing so would replace `--set-env-vars` with `--env-vars-file` and use an environment variable file to specify the value for `my_list`.

An example of how the command would change:

```
--env-vars-file=variable.yaml
```

An example of how the variable would be defined in the file:

```
my_list:["one", "two", "three"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be [`gcloud topic escaping`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping), Example:

```
gcloud compute instances create example-instance1 \
--metadata ^:^key1="value1":key2=value2:key3=value3Index1,value3Index2,valueIndex3:key4=value4
```